# I am having problem installing wkhtmltopdf on my docker container for a Django application?

Tags: django, docker, django-views, dockerfile, wkhtmltopdf

I am using pdfkit in my django application and it seems to be working fine after I installed wkhtmltopdf on my machine.
But when I build a docker image of my application for production and run it locally, it gives me OS Error for docker image. I have tried everything I found on the web but can't seem to install wkhtmltopdf on my docker container.
Here's my Docker File for building an image, this gives error while installing the package.

```
FROM python:3.6.9

RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-wheezy-amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i ~/Downloads/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-wheezy-amd64.deb

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here's the error I get in the terminal while building the image
[image]

Here's the error without wkhtmltopdf in docker
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
My DockerFile was missing some code.

```
FROM python:3.6.9

RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/shopify-managemant-app/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
RUN tar xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
RUN mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf


WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Now the image is running just fine

Answer (score 0):

This Dockerfile works with django and the newest version of wkhtmltopdf (0.12.6-1)

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9-buster

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        libxrender1 \
        libjpeg62-turbo \
        fontconfig \
        libxtst6 \
        xfonts-75dpi \
        xfonts-base \
        xz-utils
RUN curl "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb" -L -o "wkhtmltopdf.deb"

RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltopdf.deb

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```